# What are some of the rules of thumb to split a test into multiple tests?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

Okay, so I have this piece of code:

```
public TbMtUserDTO RecoverUser(long userId, UpdateTbMtUserDTO updatedData)
{
    TbMtUser user = _usersRepository.FindUserById(userId);
    if (user == null || 
       (updatedData.IdRecSet == "Password" && String.IsNullOrEmpty(updatedData.DsUpdatedPassword)))
    {
        return null;
    }

    switch (updatedData.IdRecSet)
    {
        case "Username":
            return _mapper.Map<TbMtUserDTO>(user);
        case "Password":
            user.DsPassword = PasswordHasher.Hash(updatedData.DsUpdatedPassword);
            _usersRepository.SaveChanges();
            return _mapper.Map<TbMtUserDTO>(user);
    }
    throw new InvalidOperationException(
        String.Format(RECOVER_USER_ERROR, updatedData.IdRecSet));
}
```

And while I was writing the test cases for that chunk of code, when I had to write the test for one of the "Password" case, this is what I did:

```
    [Fact]
    public void UpdatesPasswordSuccessfully()
    {
        string oldPassword = _user.DsPassword;
        UpdateTbMtUserDTO updateTbMtUserDto = new UpdateTbMtUserDTO()
        {
            IdRecSet = "Password",
            DsUpdatedPassword = "new_password"
        };
        _usersRepositoryMock
            .Setup(x => x.FindUserById(It.IsAny<long>()))
            .Returns(_user);
        _mapperMock
            .Setup(x => x.Map<TbMtUserDTO>(It.IsAny<TbMtUser>()))
            .Returns(new TbMtUserDTO());
        TbMtUserDTO userDto = _usersService.RecoverUser(_user.CdUser, updateTbMtUserDto);
        _usersRepositoryMock.Verify(x => x.SaveChanges(), Times.Once);
        Assert.NotNull(userDto);
        Assert.True(oldPassword != _user.DsPassword);
    }
```

As you can see, there are three asserts at the bottom of that test. I first check if `SaveChanges` was called, and then I verify that the method actually returned something, hence the `NotNull` assertion and that it actually modifies the password (the `True` assertion).

But I kind of feel that's not the right way to do it. But in my head those tests are related, but I'm unsure if I should split them into three different tests. The thing is that I must arrange the same pieces together for the three cases, which to be honest, I don't think it's a good idea either.

What do you guys think? I've been implementing unit-testing for a couple of months now so what are some of your rules of thumb in scenarios like these?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you think about split a test into multiple tests, you should split your method to multiple classes/methods and write tests for them? I do not want to go deep into architecture, but this can be a solution. Especially i would separate this:

```
if (user == null || (updatedData.IdRecSet == "Password" 
        && String.IsNullOrEmpty(updatedData.DsUpdatedPassword)))
{
    return null;
}
```

And this

```
user.DsPassword = PasswordHasher.Hash(updatedData.DsUpdatedPassword);
_usersRepository.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a rule that each test should test one specific aspect.  However, that leaves open a bit the question, what makes an aspect?  For me, a rule of thumb is, that two asserts represent two different aspects if there is a plausible change in the SUT that could impact only one of the two asserts.

To give you an example: Assume in some game you always start at a certain space location (maybe a space station) with a defined 3D coordinate.  To test the initialization function, you check if that initial coordinate  has the expected values.  These three values together form an aspect: If you decide at some point in time that the game should starts at a different place, all three coordinates will change at once (well, in theory not all need to change, but that would be a strange coincidence).

In your example, the situation is additionally complicated by the fact, that your function does more than one thing and uses the returning of `null` for different purposes.  To be more specific, depending on the content of the argument, the function just does a lookup (user name), or additionally makes some change (password).  Thus, it is not only a question of splitting the tests, but probably also of splitting the functionality.

I could imagine splitting it up into two parts: One function that does the lookup:

```
TbMtUser user = _usersRepository.FindUserById(userId);
if (user != null) {
    return _mapper.Map<TbMtUserDTO>(user);
} else {
    return null;
}
```

And a second one that changes the password for an already looked-up user - which in your case may not be straightforward, because the internally used type is `TbMtUser` whereas the returned type is `TbMtUserDTO` and is not clear for me how they are related...